# Handle input requests asynchronously and executing them one-by-one synchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous, zeromq, thread-synchronization

Here is the situation I am trying to achieve: User can send multiple request to perform calculations, the request should be stored in list or queue( list/queue should handle/save these request dynamically) and then one by one the request should be process. **It will process the next request once the execution of first request is completed.**

In current situation we are doing in following way:

```
  @Override
  public void execute(req) {
    synchronized (pendingRequestList) {
      pendingRequestList.add(req);
      pendingRequestList.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {

      synchronized (pendingRequestList) {
        try {
          if (pendingRequestList.size() == 0) {
            logger.debug("Waiting for new request ... ");
            pendingRequestList.wait();
          }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
          return;
        }
    }
 }
   // Perform execution synchronously
```

**In this situation if I made multiple request only one will execute and rest are expired**. I want to make all request wait in some list until execution of one is completed.

Suggest a way to maintain all request in `pendingRequestList` in `execute()` method and then execute one-by-one from that list in `run()`.

I tried following options but not getting exact way to achieve above thing:

1. Future & Future Task
2. CompletableFuture

Also I want cancel option but main is to maintain all request whenever they come in some data structure and execute them one-by-one. I am using ZMQ and fiddler to post request.

Comment: well that is very nice, but do you have a question?

Comment: @ScaryWombat First four lines what I want to achieve but unable to do.

Comment: maybe all you want is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: I don't see you "dequeue" any "task" from the list. Also, you shouldn't synchronize on the list itself in the loop, this way the thread will block when you try to add new task.

Comment: @Jai So after performing execution I am removing task from list. Also above code is for our current implementation where they are handling only one request at a time while other requests are not at all saved for processing(they gets expired).